# Kirchhoff's current law with a nonlinear resistor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity

It is said that by Kirchhoff's current law
$$
\frac{e - v_c}{R_1} = c\frac{dv}{dt} + f(v_c) + i\tag{1}
$$ 
and from Kirchhoff's voltage law
$$
v_c(t) = iR_2 + L\frac{di}{dt}\tag{2}
$$
from the following diagram:
[image]

It is easy to see equation (2) but I dont see how equation (1) was obtained.

Comment: Is this similar to a memristor? (memristor is a type of non-linear resistor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kirchhoff's current law says that the current entering any junction is equal to the current leaving that junction.

The current through $R_1$ must therefore add up to the current through the three legs of the circuit.

$$ I_{\mathrm{R}_1} = I_{\mathrm{cap}} + I_{\mathrm{nonlinear\ R}} + I_{\mathrm{R}_2} $$

Using the terms in the diagram, two of these already have an explicit label:

$$I_{\mathrm{nonlinear\ R}} = f(v_c)$$
$$I_{\mathrm{R}_2} = i $$

So we only have two other currents that need to be written in terms of the other defined variables in the diagram.

The voltage drop across $R_1$ is $e - v_c$ (the battery minus the capacitor voltage).  So the current through that resistor is
$$ I_{\mathrm{R}_1} = \frac{e - v_c}{R_1} $$

The charge on a capacitor is related to the voltage across it by $Q = C V$.  So the current through the capacitor is: 
$$I_{\mathrm{cap}} = \frac{dQ}{dt} = C \frac{d}{dt} v_c $$

Putting that all together gives:
$$\frac{e - v_c}{R_1} = c\frac{dv_c}{dt} + f(v_c) + i$$

Comment: What I found was\begin{align} e - I_1R_1 - I_2R_2 - I_2L &= 0\\ v_c - I_2R_2 - I_2L &= 0\\ v_c - I_3\text{nonlinear} &= 0\end{align} which leads to $I_1 = \frac{e - v_c}{R_1}$ then $I_1 + I_3 = I_2$. I dont know how to make the leap to the end result.

Comment: @dustin I'm not sure what exactly you are asking for clarification on.  Is there a step in my answer which is unclear to you?  Note that the voltage drop across an inductor is not IL, so some of those equations you wrote are incorrect.  Also I am unsure of why you think $I_1 + I_3 = I_2$ (that is not correct either).

Answer (score 0):

Kirchhoff's Voltage Law states that the voltage around a closed mesh or loop is zero. In this case, taking an 'imaginary loop current', $i$ around the 'central' mesh in your circuit, you get:

$$v_c(t)-v_{R2}(t)-v_L(t)=0$$

where $v_{R2}(t)$ and $v_L(t)$ are the voltage drop across the variable resistor $R_2(t)$ and inductor $L$, respectively.

[image]

I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: So do I have to make a loop around each rectangle?

Comment: @dustin Yes, if you want to solve for all voltages in the mesh. But to answer your original question, you only need to consider the central mesh and apply KVL: "voltage rises = voltage drops"

Comment: I still dont get it. $\frac{1}{c}\int i(t)dt - iR_2 - L\frac{di}{dt} = 0$ If I take the derivative, I will have $\frac{i}{c} - R\frac{di}{dt} - L\frac{d^2i}{dt^2} = 0$.

Comment: The voltage across the capacitor is $v_c(t)$, as shown on your circuit. You don't need to write it as the integral of current.

Comment: That doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Then please clarify what it is you actually need help with... You asked to find $v_c(t)$ as a function of $i$ using KVL, thats all. If you want to solve for all currents in the circuit, then modify your question to reflect this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19102/discussion-between-theo-and-dustin).